# How can i place a bootstrap button over another div which has its position as relative?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="fadein">
                 <img src="images/banner1.jpg">
                 <img src="images/banner2.jpg">
                 <img src="images/banner3.jpg">



            </div>
```

> above is my code for slide show with following css -

```
 .fadein { position:relative;
            margin-top:0px;
            top: 0px;

            }

.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
.fadein img { width:100%;  }
```

> im trying to overlay a button or a link upon this slideshow below is the anchor which i want to overlay , kindly suggest something , i am using following style rules but they are just not working .

```
   <a class="signup" href="#">Get Started</a>

     .signup{
position: absolute;
background: #F50 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: #FFF !important;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 5px;
width: 160px;
padding: 12px;
border-radius: 30px;
top: 450px;
left: 72px;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: have you considered using the bootstrap slider that's built into the API? It includes both a slider and a fader. You can also place buttons into the capotion div if you use the bootstrap slider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir, but i didn't wanted to use that slider this time , i am puzzled with this one now :/

Comment: @Azhar Are you looking for this ? [Click_this_link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the images are positioned absolutely, I assume that is part of the slider.

However, the parent element with the class of `fadein` must have a height and width to wrap around the images.

Then the link needs to be **inside** the div with the images in order that the positioning can take place with respect to the wrapper.

```css
 .fadein {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 320px;
   height: 240px;
 }
 .fadein img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .fadein img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto
 }
 .signup {
   position: absolute;
   background: #F50 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
   color: #FFF !important;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   width: 160px;
   padding: 12px;
   border-radius: 30px;
   top: 10%;
   /* or whatever */
   left: 10%;
   /* or whatever */
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" alt=""> <a class="signup" href="#">Get Started</a>

</div>
```